# Why is form.submit() not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following snipet in a page. I cannot for the life of me figure out why the form is not submitting when clicking the button1 element. I get an error in IE syaing that this object does not support this property or method. I put the document.poform in an alert, and it alerts a form object. I get the feeling that I am missing something super obvious maybe??

```
<pre>
<?
    var_dump($_POST);
?>
</pre>
<form action="" method="post" name="poform">
    <input name="test" type="text" />
    <input name="button" type="button" value="button1" onclick="document.poform.submit();" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="button2" />
</form>
```

Comment: @Gabe: no action means "submit to the same url the form was loaded from".

Comment: @Gabe defining no action simply submits to self.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have an `<input>` named `submit`, `document.poform.submit` is that `<input>`, not the `submit()` method.

Use a different name.

Comment: In fact, don't do document.poform - give it an ID and access it via document.getElementById('whatever')

Answer (score -2):

Change type="button" to type="submit"