# Javascript select onchange='this.form.submit()'

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have a form with a select and a few text inputs. I'd like the form to be submitted when the select is changed. This works fine using the following:

```
onchange="this.form.submit()"
```

However, if the form also contains a submit button, then the form does not submit when the select is changed. I'm guessing some kind of conflict.

What are my options here?

Should I use something like
`$(this.form).trigger("submit")` 
instead?

Comment: Provide a testcase that exhibits the issue, so that we can answer you without wild guessing

Comment: Make sure your button doesn't have a name or id attribute of "submit", I've seen this as interfering before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736341/why-is-form-submit-not-working

Comment: As a general rule, auto-submitting forms when a control changes is a really bad idea from a usability and accessibility standpoint. See [WCAG - F36: Failure of Success Criterion 3.2.2 due to automatically submitting a form and presenting new content without prior warning when the last field in the form is given a value](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/F36.html) and [WCAG - G13: Describing what will happen before a change to a form control that causes a change of context to occur is made](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G13.html)

Comment: Check your browser's javascript error log. this.form.submit() is standard Javascript so it should work.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should be able to use something similar to:

```
$('#selectElementId').change(
    function(){
         $(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');
         /* or:
         $('#formElementId').trigger('submit');
            or:
         $('#formElementId').submit();
         */
    });
```

Answer (score 25):

My psychic debugging skills tell me that your submit button is named `submit`.
Therefore, `form.submit` refers to the button rather than the method.

Rename the button to something else so that `form.submit` refers to the method again.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm just guessing.  This has come up several times before; it matches his problem perfectly.

Comment: OK; perhaps your answer should say "**Perhaps** your submit button is named `submit`".

Comment: No, @Tomalak, Much cooler to assume the likely situation :) Makes you look like a star when the asker hits his forehead ;)

Comment: @mplungjan: It also fails to teach them about how they did not provide ample information in their question.

Comment: @Tomalak: True.  I would hope that they would realize that anyway, though.

Comment: @SLaks: Were that the case, I think they would have done it right in the first place!

Comment: @mplungjan: Not at all. The perfect answer, I think, is like SLaks's, but with a "But I am only guessing because you did not provide any sort of testcase nor ample information in your question" at the end. :)

Comment: You're right.  I think this edit drives the point home more strongly.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using jQuery, it's as simple as this:

```
 $('#mySelect').change(function()
 {
     $('#myForm').submit();
 });
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways this can be completed.

Elements know which form they belong to, so you don't need to wrap `this` in jquery, you can just call `this.form` which returns the form element. Then you can call `submit()` on a form element to submit it.

```
  $('select').on('change', function(e){
    this.form.submit()
  });
```

documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Comment: This is the best answer. You don't always have to do *everything* in jQuery - you can mix'n'match where appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Bind them using jQuery and make jQuery handle it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmxpW/.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: @mplungjan: But he's talking about `$().trigger`. I assume he's already using jQuery.

Comment: argh, @mplungjan edited his comment as I +1'd the original. >.< Please don't do that; if you're changing the content of your comment, write a new one and delete the original instead.

Comment: Ok. Apologies. I only changed it because the asker actually DID use jQuery... The impact of my change was small - from No, jQuery is not needed to submit onchange, to if jQuery is already used :)

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">

    function myFunction() {
        document.querySelectorAll("input[type=submit]")[0].click();
    }
```