# This.Form.Submit() on CakePHP

Tags: javascript, forms, cakephp

I am working on my first CakePHP project.

I am building a form on a page and want the form to submit after selecting a option in a `<SELECT>` atribute

Normally (Not in Cake) I use the option `onchange="this.form.submit();"`

But for some reason my form in Cake refuses to submit the form.

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check answer here
[Javascript select onchange='this.form.submit()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261305/javascript-select-onchange-this-form-submit)

Why dont you use jquery. its simple 
include jquery , give form and select input a id . then use following code

```
$('#selectElementId').change(
function(){

     $('#formElementId').submit();

});
```